# 「初めての質問」レビューの選択肢の説明が分かりづらい

Tags: サポート, レビュー

よく読むとすべての選択肢に意味不明な点がありました。ヘルプを見ても理解できません。

#### OK

> (必ずそれに応じて投票してください)

投票とは質問に対するupvote/downvoteのことでしょうか？だとすると任意であるはずの投票がなぜレビューを処理すると強制になるのか理解できません。

#### 編集 / フィードバック

文言はよいのですが、このアクションを選択するとどうなるのでしょうか。次の画面で該当の操作ができる？この画面または元の質問画面でそれをやる？

#### その他のアクション

なぜ選択できない選択肢があるのですか。何かをしたら選択できるようになる？

---

**「初めての質問」レビューの選択肢**

[image: 「初めての質問」レビューの選択肢]

Answer (score 2):

#### OK

> 投票とは質問に対するupvote/downvoteのことでしょうか？
> だとすると任意であるはずの投票がなぜレビューを処理すると強制になるのか理解できません。

認識の通り、(質問の質に応じて)「プラス票またはマイナス票を入れてください」で合っています。

個人的にも「投票が強制」っぽく読み取れてしまうのは気になっているところで、見直しをかけたい部分ではあります。原文は "be sure to vote accordingly" ですが、英語に詳しくないのでどう訳すのがより適切なのかは議論の余地がありそうです。

#### 編集 / フィードバック

- 「編集」を選択して「送信」すると、そのまま「質問の編集画面」に遷移します。
- 「フィードバック」を選択して「送信」すると、一般的なコメントのテンプレート、または自分自身でコメントを残すためのポップアップが表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### その他のアクション

例えば「クローズ」票を入れたり、「通報」を行う、もしくは (本文下部にある) [編集] を直接行った場合等に「その他のアクション」が選択可能になる…はずです。

Answer (score 2):

### 「OK」 の際に投票が必要？

「この質問は、趣旨が明確でわかりやすい・実用的である・建設的である」ならば、プラス投票できるはずです。特に指摘する点が無いのであればプラス投票すべきなので、それをしてくださいという文言だと思われます。

なお、投票が強制されている訳ではなく、レビューせずにスキップを選択することもできます。

### 「編集」「フィードバックを共有」を選択するとどうなる？

「編集」を選ぶと編集画面に、「フィードバックを共有」を選択するとフィードバックコメントの投稿画面に移ります。

### 「その他のアクション」は選択できない？

これは編集など特定のアクションをすると選択できるようになります。何もしない状態だと選択できません。

---

「OK」のときの投票は、元のテキストだと "be sure to vote accordingly" という書き方になっていて、確かに直訳すると「必ずそれに応じて投票してください」なのですがもう少し書き方は工夫できるかもしれません（が、思いつけていません）。

下ふたつは、やってみれば分かるので自分はそこまで違和感を覚えませんでした。誘導のための文字列を足しても良いかもしれませんが元のテキストも似たような文言なので、Meta Stack Exchange においてそちらを変えていくようにはたらきかけるのはアリかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

こちらのヘルプ記事に書かれた内容が行われやすくなるように設計・実装されているのだと思われます。(本当に投票が無いとレビューが完了しないとかだと強制と言えそうですが)

[初めての質問投稿キューを使用するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions)

> - 新しいユーザーを励ますためにも、上手く書かれた質の良い質問にプラス票を投じてください。

---

英語版

[How do I use the First questions queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions)

> - Upvote good, well-written questions to encourage new users.

---

こんなまとめ記事とかあるし、(確かめてはいませんが)おそらくStackExchange関連の全サイトが同様の仕様でしょうから、まあ文言としては許容範囲なのでは？
[日本人はレビューですぐ低評価をつけたりおかしなクレームを入れてくるので、他の国から避けられがちになっている？](https://togetter.com/li/1938934)
こちらは元中の人による生の声[【コラム】日本人の評価が辛いぞ問題](https://a2i.jp/column/post-26086/)